# Normalizing/denormalizing state with angular-redux

Tags: angular, normalizr, angular-redux, ngrx-entity

I have started a new project with **angular-redux** and I really like the setup, all is working well. However, the complexity will grow soon and I'm concerned with the store state will become too deep, arrays within arrays - you guys know the drill.

Best solution seems to be to normalize the state (ngrx/entity functionality), however I can not find a solution for this with angular-redux, is there a recommended approach?

Comment: I would shape the state according to how the components want to use it to make selectors as simple as possible (although angular-redux `select$` takes a transform function). Any transformations needed best done in actions, reducers or middleware.

Comment: I think you find it usefull 1. https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape 2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-combine-reducers